# parse.com Save object with realation. Android

Tags: android, object, parse-platform, relation

let`s say I have two objects (classes) Category and Work. I want to save new Work with Category relation.
Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty basic thing covered in the [documentation here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers).

In your case you would have a `category` property on your `Work` object that would be an object pointer to a `Category` class (table).

```
// assuming you have myWork and myCategory as instances of ParseObject
myWork.put('category', myCategory);
```

If you only have the objectId of the `Category` then you do the following:

```
myWork.put('category', ParseObject.createWithoutData('Category', categoryId));
```

Comment: Yes, I found it. And my mistake was to create relation instead of pointer column. Thanks!

Comment: But this is a way to make pointer. how to make relations? say you want to create new works that are related to a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

But now I want to get info from database.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
        query.whereEqualTo("user", userID);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
          public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
              System.out.println(commentList);
          }
        });
```

And after that I got empty response.

**SOLVED.**